# What is stored in the modelview matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix

I have been trying to learn more about matrices in opengl; right now I'm stuck trying to understand where things are stored inside the modelview matrix. (location,scaling,rotations etc) This is obviously very important as understanding matrices is one of the first steps to fully understand modern opengl.

I have been trying to find some good articles, and I've currently found 2: ([1](http://www.geeks3d.com/20141114/glsl-4x4-matrix-mat4-fields/),[2](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.se/2009/09/opengl-matrix-tricks-camera-properties.html))

However, I stil don't understand where the values are stored; any help is very appreciated (links, pinpointers etc)

Comment: There is an abundance of information in the literature and on the web and  on how vertex transformation works. One (IMHO) good source is [this one](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html). There is also a more general article on transformation matrices [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Comment: Sorry; I removed those tags (as I wasn't quoting anyone) That source looks interesting, I'll look into it.

Comment: That's not related to C++, but school maths. Not ever really about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference of how different (affine) transformation matrices are constructed:

**Identity**:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

**Translate** (x, y ,z):

```
1 0 0 x
0 1 0 y
0 0 1 z
0 0 0 1
```

**Scale** (sx, sy, sz):

```
sx  0  0  0
 0 sy  0  0
 0  0 sz  0
 0  0  0  1
```

**Rotate along x axis** (by angle t):

```
 1  0       0      0
 0 cos(t) -sin(t)  0
 0 sin(t)  cos(t)  0
 0  0       0      1
```

**Rotate along y axis** (by angle t):

```
cos(t)  0 sin(t)  0
 0      1   0     0
-sin(t) 0 cos(t)  0
 0      0   0     1
```

**Rotate along z axis** (by angle t):

```
cos(t) -sin(t)  0   0
sin(t)  cos(t)  0   0
 0       0      1   0
 0       0      0   1
```